# How to amplify the resistance of LDR between 500-900 Ohms for use as Arduino input (0-5V)

Tags: operational-amplifier, ldr

I have a LDR which I want to use for measuring the light level between two intensities, which are a pretty small part of its full range.

[image]

Basically the LDR ranges from about 300ohms to 2.5Mohms measured on DVM, but I am really only interested in its output between 500-800ohms. So I'd like to squash values below 500 to 0v, and set that to 5v when the R is above 800 ohms.

The basic circuit only gives about 0.1 of a volt difference over the resistances I am interested in. I can change the value of the R1 resistor to 600ohms, and get about 1V of difference, but I'd still like to use the whole range of the Arduino adc 12bits;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD7TKP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am currently using an arduino to read the voltage level between 0-5v. I presume I am looking for some sort of wheatstone bridge, or voltage divider  and op-amp set-up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn6ANN.png)</sup>

Comment: Do you only have a 5 V rail, or do you have say -5 and +12 as well?

Comment: I am using an Arduino uno, so I really only have 3.3 and 5V to work with. I could add an external supply if it made things really easy and there was no other way.

Comment: Change R1 to 600Ω and use the internal 1.1V reference voltage for the ADC?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your circuit is that the load resistor is mismatched to the resistance range of the sensor you care about.  The sensor in series with a resistor gives you a voltage that varies as a function of the full sensor range, from 0 to ∞.  However, the resulution is highest in the middle of the range, which is when the sensor and the load resitances are equal.

Therefore the solution is to use your top circuit but make R1 640 Ω instead of 10 kΩ.  That also produces a low enough impedance signal that you can directly connect it to the A/D input of most microcontrollers.

With a 640 Ω load resistor you get 2.58 V at 600 Ω and 2.22 V at 800 Ω, for a 360 mV difference between the two light levels you care about.  With a 10 bit A/D, which is common in microcontrollers nowadays, that's 73 counts.  Many micros are available with 12 bit A/D now, which would get you over 290 counts, or about 1/3%.  That's more accurate than your LDR sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use a physical mask to limit the amount of light that the photocell sees?

This is how the older automatic light sensors for outdoor street lighting work: they use a big-ass CdS photocell directly driving a relay.  They control the sensitivity of the system by using an adjustable metal mask that shades part of the photocell - this allows easy tuning of when the street light turns ON and OFF.

Comment: You mean put a handful of the LDR:s in series.

Comment: I don't have this option available unfortunately.

Comment: @Johan: That still wouldn't do anything useful.  You still have the same ratio of dark to light resistance.  All you're doing is shifting the mid range resistance point.  You can get the same voltage range out of the divider by shifting the load resistor instead of adjusting the LDR resistance.

Comment: I came across some where the mask was silver paint over the large area LDR that was scratched away to allow the correct amount of light to operate the bimetallic thermal relay to power the output.  However as @OlinLathrop wrote this technique merely provides more current handling and can be used to set one calibration point.  It does not do level and gain shifting.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (R3 is your sensor, VS1 represents the 5 V power supply, VM3 measures the output voltage):

[image: circuit]

The two transistors will give you a constant current of about 5 mA (can be changed by modifying R1), which would make your sensor output ~2.5 V at 500 ohm and ~4 V at 800 ohm. A rail-to-rail opamp (MCP6002 on the picture, but a single MCP6001 is okay as well) translates this into a wider range (about 0.08 V at 500 ohm and 4.85 V at 800 ohm) and also provides a reasonably low impedance drive to your ADC input. The offset can be changed by modifying R7 / R8, the amplification can be changed by modifying R6.

The output function is like:
[image: output]

Comment: simulated in Qucs this looks pretty good, I'm just working out some equivalent components to the BC557C, TL431 and MCP6002 which I don't have to hand.

Comment: Any pair of small-signal PNP transistors will do. For the TL431, the easy substitutes would be the TL431-clones :) For the MCP6002, you'll need a rail-to-rail opamp. Or get an external power supply with >7V output, and use an LM324 powered from that power supply. Actually, all these parts are pretty common and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

The atmel docs provide impedence matching information in their datasheets.  If you can't use the internal ADC by itself, maybe a simple amplifier would be cheap and applicable?

Noninverting Amplifier circuit

[image: Noninverting Amplifier circuit]

The gain is easily computed by:

Vout/Vin = R2/(R1+R2) = 1 + R2/R1

So, simply, if r2 is 10k and r1 is 1k it's a 10x gain.  Neat:)

Of course it's really 11x's, but who's counting...

I think you can probably do this with only the micro, might want to do some googling and hit the data sheet.  Also look at application notes for the atmel device(s) your using.

I'm making one for the kitchen, which I cruise through at night, so I need to measure exactly that and make the PWM adjusted to keep the LED's at the proper level.  I'm not adding more hardware if I can help it....

Good luck..

Jack

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.  The original question was looking for a way to map a certain range of brightness to the full scale of the ADC.  The question wasn't about matching impedance.  There is need of an op-amp with gain, but it must also shift the level down so that besides needing the gain you also need to provide an offset.  If I were you, I'd delete this before it gets downvoted.